# Disable scroll makes content to move right

Tags: javascript, html, css

Have a look at this website please [ebooks.am](https://ebooks.am)

So when I click on a table row, the sidebar opens from right side. Here I give body disable scroll for two purposes: first is definitely to disable scroll in body when sidebar is opened and the second is to hide scroll bar in sidebar, otherwise I would have 2 scrollbars side by side. 

My problem is that when a sidebar is opened, the content (centered table, search) is moved to right. So how can I fix this, to make the content stay at the same place where it is.

Thanks in regards

Comment: Please go read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it

Comment: This is happening because, when the browser scrollbars disappear, that gives the window slightly more width, which repositions the main container (since it is centered using `auto` for margin-left and largin-right). Unfortunately I can't think of a simple way to fix it while keeping the scroll disabled when the menu is open. [ Actually I just thought of one way that might work - set the `overflow-y` to `scroll` rather than `hidden` - then the scrollbar will always be there. Unfortunately that won't behave right if the table fits in the window without scrolling.]

Comment: thank you, that doens't really solve my problem for 100%, but in any case, thank you.

Answer (score -1):

add "disable-scroll" class on html element and add the following code

```
  html.disable-scroll{
        height: 100vh;
        overflow: hidden;
    }

    html.disable-scroll body{
        overflow: scroll;
    }
```

Comment: actually your answer almost solved my problem. the only point is that the content shift is happening when I open sidebar for the first time and stays at the same position for next openings

Comment: It is happening every time on my pc I am using chrome on windows every browser and os implement scroll differently.